# weak*-null sequences in the dual space of a separable space

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable space and let $x^{**}\in X^{**}$. If $x^{**}(x^{*}_{n})\rightarrow 0$ for each weak*-null sequence $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}$ in $X^{*}$, is $x^{**}$ in $X$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: A Banach space $X$ has Mazur property if every weak* sequentially continuous linear $\mu:X^{\ast} \to\mathbb{C}$ is (weak* continuous, so) in $X$. In this language, separable Banach spaces have Mazur property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $(B_{X^*},w^*)$ is compact metrizable. So $x^{**}$ is $w^*$-continuous at any $x^*\in B_{X^*}$.